# Always choose index 0 if list appears in Python Dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am iterating over a python `dict` that I am parsing from an `XML` file however, sometimes the `dict` can have a `list` for the element which results in this error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

How can I always choose index 0 if there is more than one record per element?

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO table (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 12) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
             [(x['@xsi:type'].split(':')[1],
               x['N2:OrganisationName']['N2:NameElement']['#text'],
               x['N5:Addresses']['N5:Address'][0]['N6:FreeTextAddress']['N6:AddressLine'][0]['#text'],
               x['N5:Addresses']['N5:Address'][0]['N6:FreeTextAddress']['N6:AddressLine'][1]['#text'],
               x['N5:Addresses']['N5:Address'][0]['N6:FreeTextAddress']['N6:AddressLine'][2]['#text'],
               x['N5:Addresses']['N5:Address'][0]['N6:PostCode']['N6:Identifier']['#text'],
               x['N5:Identifiers']['N5:Identifier']['N5:IdentifierElement'],
               x['N5:OrganisationInfo']['@N5:Type'],
               x['N5:OrganisationInfo']['@N5:Status'],
               x['N5:OrganisationInfo']['@N5:IndustryCode'],
               x['N1:Director']['@xsi:type'].split(':')[1],
               x['N1:Director']['N2:PersonName']['N2:NameElement'][0]['#text'] + " " + x['N1:Director']['N2:PersonName']['N2:NameElement'][1]['#text']
               )
              for x in doc['N8:EntityList']['N8:Entity']])
```

For example: 
most common output

```
>>> print (doc['N8:EntityList']['N8:Entity'][4]['N1:Director']['@xsi:type'])
N9:CompanyDirector
```

Then sometimes it can look like this as there are multiple records

```
>>> print (doc['N8:EntityList']['N8:Entity'][5]['N1:Director'][0]['@xsi:type'])
N9:CompanyDirector
>>> print (doc['N8:EntityList']['N8:Entity'][5]['N1:Director'][1]['@xsi:type'])
N9:CompanyDirector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is a fragment of your dictionary:

```
doc = {'N8:EntityList': {'N8:Entity': [{'N1:Director': [{'@xsi:type': 'Foo'}]}]}}
```

I assume that you have a list of keys for each item of interest:

```
path = ['N8:EntityList', 'N8:Entity', 'N1:Director', '@xsi:type']
```

Iterate through the keys, one level at a time, checking if the next keyed object is a list or not. In the former case, take its first element:

```
e = doc
for key in path:
    e = e[key][0] if isinstance(e[key], list) else e[key]
print(e)
#Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

DyZ's solution would work, for options sake I'll show another way to do it. You could use a try except statement. Using your small example from above:

```
try:
    print (doc['N8:EntityList']['N8:Entity'][4]['N1:Director']['@xsi:type'])
except TypeError:
    print (doc['N8:EntityList']['N8:Entity'][5]['N1:Director'][0]['@xsi:type'])
```

If you don't know what try catch statements are there is lots of helpful documentation if you google it, but here are a couple of resources (for python 2.7).

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html

https://www.python-course.eu/exception_handling.php